# VBA - Excel - On Error goto userform

Tags: vba, error-handling, excel

When there is an error, I want to go back to my userform and change the information entered on the form and re pass it into the macro and then continue from: If Len(Dir(sFilePath & newfol, vbDirectory)) = 0...

```
If Len(Dir(sFilePath & newfol, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            MkDir sFilePath & newfol & "\"
            On Error GoTo UserForm1
        Else
            MsgBox ("Folder already exists please re enter new folder name")
            'End
            UserForm1.Show
            MoveAndSave_Reports
End If
```

The above give me an error message: Compile error: Label not defined at "On Error GoTO UserForm1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use an "On Error GoTo" statement, you're telling the program that when it hits an error, skip to a specific line in the current procedure. For example:

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
x = 10 / 0
msgbox "x = infinity!"

ErrorHandler:
msgbox "Cannot divide by zero"
```

In this example, when the code hits an error (after my "On Error" statement), it will stop what it's doing and begin executing code at the ErrorHandler label (it's a label because of the colon at the end). Running this code, you would never see the message box saying x = infinity. Once it hits the error by trying to divide by zero, it will jump down to the ErrorHandler label and give me a message saying I can't divide by zero.

Chip Pearson has a good introduction to basic error handling [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm).

Comment: As an add on to what Craig has said, make a label and then write some code to call the user form and do what needs to be done.